# Get Supported Countries from Ringcaptcha in Android

Tags: android, runtimeexception

I'm implementing my own UI to use Ringcaptcha and I need to show a list of all available countries so the user can select one of them.

I'm using the following code:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        List<RingcaptchaCountry> countries = RingcaptchaApplication.getSupportedCountries(this);
        ...
}
```

When I ran this code it crashes in the following line:

List countries = RingcaptchaApplication.getSupportedCountries(this);

with this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackage.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference.
```

How should I call getSupportedCountries?

Thanks in advance!